# Rewrite http://example.com/any/path to http://example.com/any with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite the URI in case of non existing files – which should be my views – like this:

`http://example.com/test/path/example` → `http://example.com/test`

I'm already removing trailing slashes with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

What do I have to add to my `.htaccess` file to get the desired functionality?

Comment: In your actual rule you are passing the URL-path to the substitution URL, so when the path should be removed and when should be passed?

Comment: @faa If it contains a slash, the first slash and everything after that should be removed.

Comment: But in your rule it must have a trailing slash also, so what's the difference?

Comment: @faa I just presented my existing rule to tell that I am already doing `example/test/path/` → `example/test/path`, so maybe this can be extended to what I want to achieve. But probably I just need an other rule instead of the existing one that removes the first slash and everything after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the rule-set in the question is not used, you may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/.+/?  $1?  [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://example.com/folder/with/any/path` or any query

To:

`http://example.com/folder`

All strings are assumed to be variable.

For silent mapping replace [R=301,L] with [L]

Comment: I edited my question to clear the misunderstanding; sorry for being so ambiguous!

Comment: So you need to remove any path after `http://example/test`. Right?

Comment: `test` is not supposed to be fixed, but thanks anyway! :) If I am right `^\w+/.+/?` should match any word. Does this also work for like `http://example/test/` → `http://example/test`?

Comment: @Daniel Updated again.